# How to create a circular slider with breakpoints?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-svg, react-native-stylesheet

I am new to react-native and i want to achieve the below design in react-native

[image: Image link]

[image: I am trying to achieve this]

- The blue circle is a slider to chose the date(Date Picker)
- The circle inside the slider(Date Picker) changes color when the date is changed
- and finally an image inside the circle.

it would be great if anyone could provide links for reference or a library which i can use to create the design shown in the image.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post the code showing what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to create a custom SVG Slider just like this one

I have created a sample for you take a look

[react-native-circular-slider-with-breakpoints](https://github.com/rizshivalli/react-native-circular-slider-with-breakpoints)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Well this is a custom slider which has some break point values. As the slider changes there is a change in the state and based on that the below description view is rendered.

[Use this slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-slider-custom) and give some css colors and styles to make it round